# HBase region servers going down with error DataXceiver error processing WRITE_BLOCK operation

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have AWS cluster, Cloudera Hadoop Distribution version 5.4 configured with 1 namenode and 2 datanodes

I have HBase table with 100K records and performing scan operation on top this table by using Java. As per the user selection at front end I will be generating where conditions on different columns in the table to fetch the records.

When I have multiple filter conditions and trying to fetch the data from HBase table I'm getting the following exception

```
node3.xxx.com:50010:DataXceiver error processing WRITE_BLOCK operation  src: /xxx.xx.xx.194:58862 dst: /xxx.xx.xx.193:50010
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF from inputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


node3.xxx.com:50010:DataXceiver error processing WRITE_BLOCK operation  src: /xxx.xx.xx.194:35615 dst: /xxx.xx.xx.193:50010
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF from inputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doReadFully(PacketReceiver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.doRead(PacketReceiver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PacketReceiver.receiveNextPacket(PacketReceiver.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receivePacket(BlockReceiver.java:466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockReceiver.receiveBlock(BlockReceiver.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opWriteBlock(Receiver.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The following are the dependency that I have added to connect to HBase using Java

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The following is the java code that I'm using to fetch the records from HBase table

```
public synchronized List<Map<String, String>> getFilterData(Map<String, String> map) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Table table = null;
    ResultScanner resultScanner = null;

    List<Map<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {
        connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
        table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(fileReader.getProperty("HBASE_FILTER_DATA_TABLE_NAME")));

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setCaching(1000);
        scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("avgValue"));
        scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("ts"));
        scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("dataType"));

        SingleColumnValueFilter ageGroupFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("ageGroup"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("-1"));
        SingleColumnValueFilter applicationFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("appName"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("-1"));
        SingleColumnValueFilter deviceFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("deviceModel"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("-1"));
        SingleColumnValueFilter genderFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("gender"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("-1"));

        if (map.containsKey("ageGroup")) {
            ageGroupFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("ageGroup"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(map.get("ageGroup")));
            scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("ageGroup"));
        }

        if (map.containsKey("appName")) {
            applicationFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("appName"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(map.get("appName").toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_")));
            scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("appName"));
        }

        if (map.containsKey("deviceModel")) {
            deviceFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("deviceModel"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(map.get("deviceModel").toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_")));
            scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("deviceModel"));
        }

        if (map.containsKey("gender")) {
            genderFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("gender"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(map.get("gender").toLowerCase()));
            scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("gender"));
        }

        FilterList filters = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
        filters.addFilter(ageGroupFilter);
        filters.addFilter(applicationFilter);
        filters.addFilter(deviceFilter);
        filters.addFilter(genderFilter);

        if (map.containsKey("dataType")) {
            SingleColumnValueFilter dataTypeFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("filter"), Bytes.toBytes("dataType"), CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(map.get("dataType").toLowerCase()));
            filters.addFilter(dataTypeFilter);
        }

        if (map.containsKey("startDate") && map.containsKey("endDate")) {
            String startDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(map.get("startDate"))));
            String endDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(map.get("endDate"))));

            SingleColumnValueFilter startDateFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("hour"), CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(startDate));
            SingleColumnValueFilter endDateFilter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("data"), Bytes.toBytes("hour"), CompareOp.LESS_OR_EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes(endDate));

            filters.addFilter(startDateFilter);
            filters.addFilter(endDateFilter);
        }

        scan.setFilter(filters);

        resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);

        for (Result result = resultScanner.next(); result != null; result = resultScanner.next()) {
            Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (Cell cell : result.listCells()) {
                row.put(Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell)), Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(cell)));
            }

            resultList.add(row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in getFilterData() : ", e.getMessage(), e); 
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultScanner != null) {
                resultScanner.close();
            }

            if (table != null) {
                table.close();
            }

            if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: Hi Prasad. I don't know if this will help, but I would start using a try-with-resources block and remove the finally, so I'd be sure that I have done no error in the finally block. It's worth a try ;)